# How merge and sum values at same time - python

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to create a webscraping script about football data.But I'm facing a issue in the return of my code, the values of each player are being doubled. I will use a example of 'Harry Kane':
[image]

how to add the values of goals and assists in such a way that there is only one line for each player, and not two lines (with NaN values).
I have 209 rows with the same issue
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby`:

```
>>> df.groupby("player", as_index=False).agg({"team": "first", 
                                              "country": "first", 
                                              "gols": "sum", 
                                              "assist": "sum"})
```

Comment: Thanks man, you helped me a lot. All the best :)

Comment: *woman ;). Happy to help! :)